# Sharing code between UITableViewCell & UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclasses

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

Currently, I've a `UITableViewCell` subclass that has the same view as `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass. I setup the subclass views programmatically that includes a bunch of UILabels and UIImageviews. Currently, I've just copy/pasted the code between the two files. I was wondering if there is a way to consolidate code. I can't inherit code as UITableViewCell and `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` are different. I'm guessing the right answer is through the use of protocols but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to actually implement it. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: How about create a view and add it as a subview for both UITableViewCell and UItableViewHeaderFooterView?

Comment: Add code to the question, it helps to answer better.